# How can I access a class inside another class / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I have my main class A

```
export class A {

    public sourceReference: string;

    public charge: Charge;
}
```

my Charge class looks like such:

```
export class Charge {

    public chargeType: string;
    
    public chargeAccountNumber: string;

    public chargeCurrency: string;
}
```

In my index file I want to use my main class A and populate my payload as follows:

```
    import { A } from "./a";
    
    public static create(payload) {

      let myData = new A();

      myData.sourceReference = payload.sourceRef;
      myData.charge.chargeType = payload.type;
      myData.charge.chargeAccountNumber = payload.accountNumber;
      myData.charge.chargeCurrency = payload.currency

      return JSON.stringify(myData)

     }
```

my incoming payload file looks like such:

```
payload = { sourceRef: "1234", type: '615-01', accountNumber: '123456', currency: 'USD'}
```

I am able to generate         **myData.sourceReference**

However,

The problem is that `myData.charge` is returning as undefined, resulting in undefined values for `myData.charge.chargeType`, `myData.charge.chargeAccountNumber` & `myData.charge.chargeCurrency`.

Exception: TypeError: Cannot set property 'chargeType' of undefined

Comment: The `Cannot set property 'chargeType' of undefined` error pretty much exactly tells you what's wrong: you need to _define_ `myData.charge` before you can assign it property values. Make that a real thing first, _then_ copy over the chargeType etc.

Comment: Try doing `myData.charge = new Charge();`

Comment: or better yet - let `A`'s constructor create the data needed.

Answer (score 1):

Class `A` has a property of the class `Charge`.

Having said that, the `charge` property only has a type - but no instance.

The class `A` will have to create an instance of the class `Charge` somewhere - mostly in the constructor.

The constructor should look like this:

```
export class A {

  public sourceReference: string;
  public charge: Charge;

  constructor() {
     this.charge = new Charge()
  }

 ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time Charlie!
I applied this and it worked fine. However, when I add other similar classes to the constructor they all appear in the resultant payload as blank strings. Ultimately, I'd like to build the payload differently based on different scenarios. Also, as mentioned in my response to Sebastian, I would have liked to avoid importing all these sub classes into my index file if possible. (As Ive already imported them into my main A class)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you what's the problem. You have to define myData.charge, using `myData.charge = new Charge()` and then define it's properties like

```
myData.charge.chargeType = payload.type;
myData.charge.chargeAccountNumber = payload.accountNumber;
myData.charge.chargeCurrency = payload.currency
```

Or if you want to be fancy, you can create a constructor for charge like this:

```
export class Charge {
    
    constructor(chargeType:string, chargeAccountNumber:string, chargeCurrency:string){
    this.chargeType = chargeType;
    this.chargeAccountNumber = chargeAccountNumber;
    this.chargeCurrency=chargeCurrency;
    }

    public chargeType: string;

    public chargeAccountNumber: string;

    public chargeCurrency: string;
}
```

And then you can call the constructor like

```
myData.charge = new Charge(chargeType,chargeAccountNumber,chargeCurrency)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sebastian, New to StackOverflow so sorry if Im not following the prescribed formats.
I probably should have mentioned that I did try to create a new instance of Charge in my index file but failed to get that right, so trying your method worked and thank you for that. 
I was , however, looking for a solution that doesn't involve me importing all these classes into my index file. (I've already imported all of them into my main class (A Class). The examples I provided are samples and my actual main class is much bigger with other class types inside it. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you should reformulate your question or open a new one with more in depth data about your code. What do you mean with your index file? Are you using any Typescript framework? Typescript is all about importing, being strongly typed, unlike javascript, you'll face a lot of importing. Any class you want to use on any file you'll have to import it.